# Migration of rule project from IBM ODM 8.5 to 8.9v

Tags: ibm-odm

Is it possible to migrate IBM ODM Rule project of 8.5v to Decision service in 8.9v.
what precaution need to taken while migration?

Answer (score 0):

yes, migration from 8.5 to 8.9 is possible. IBM provides a wizard, but manual steps are required. I have not used the wizard in 8.9, but used it several times in 8.7. Should be similar. Here are my notes.

---

**How to Migrate Classic Rule Projects to Decision Services**

This document provides a brief recipe for converting from ‘classic’ rule projects to the new ‘decision service’ style rule projects in ODM v8.7.1.1.

***IBM Knowledge Center References***

Migrating classic rule projects to decision services    http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.7.1/com.ibm.odm.distrib.migrating/odm_topics/tsk_migrate_projects_to_ds.html

**Procedure**

1. Open the Rule Designer workspace that contains the classic rule projects that you want to migrate.
2. Verify the migration pre-requisites have been met (see the Knowledge Center reference), including the verbalization of the ruleset parameters.
3. From the Rules perspective, click the Rule Projects Migration icon (looks like a folder with a green arrow pointing to the right) in the toolbar.
4. Follow the steps in the migration wizard.
5. Select all the rule projects at once
6. Let the wizard do its work.
7. Review Rule Project Migration reports for each rule project
8. Clean and Build the workspace
9. Rename the rule projects, if required for new naming standards (your company, not IBM ODM).
10. Change the Decision Service property of the Main Rule Project to be Standard Rule Project.
11. Create a new Decision Service Main Rule Project that references all the other rule projects with an appropriate name, like *DecisionService*.
12. Move the contents of the deployment folder from the project that originally specified the parameters to the new Main Rule Project created in the previous step. This folder should contain a new ‘operation’ corresponding to each ruleset in the Classic Rule Projects.
13. Rename the operation in the Main Rule Project to match the previous Rule App name.
14. Edit the operation in the Main Rule Project to change the Source Rule Project to be the Main Rule Project.
15. Edit the operation in the Main Rule Project to change the Ruleflow to ‘Use main ruleflow’ and specify the Main ruleflow.
16. Edit the operation in the Main Rule Project to change the Ruleset Name to match the previous ruleset name.
17. Add an Action Task to some ruleflow to initialize any ruleset variables that were previously initialized directly from the ‘parameter’. 
    Note: With Classic Rule Projects, the Initial Value of a ruleset variable could be set to the value of a ruleset parameter. With Decision Service Rule Projects, there is no longer any such thing as a ruleset parameter – you must define a ruleset variable to hold that value. Since the Initial Value of a ruleset variable cannot be set to the value of another ruleset variable, it is no longer possible to use the Initial Value to set the ruleset variables that were used as ‘virtual parameters’; instead, these ruleset variables now should be initialized in the Main rule flow in either (a) the Initial Actions of the Initialize rule task or (b) in an action task.
18. You should be able to run DVS tests from Rule Designer, or publish the Main Rule Project to Decision Center and run Decision Runner tests from the Business Console.